# Cannot copy large files normally

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

Win 7 64bit. Why do i need to rename a large file say 5gb to be able to copy it over to another drive. No matter if its from a sata drive or a flash drive. First I try to copy the file (we'll call it file 1) and let it fail after a few seconds. then i leave that failed file (File 1)in the destination drive and rename the original file to file 2. Now it will copy just fine to the destination drive. This will also happen with folders containing a very large number of small files too. Please Help.

Thank you for replying. I do not change the file extension just the name. the tab is under general already. By the way i forgot to mention after renaming the folder i have to copy and past it to the new location. I cannot drag an drop large files or folders. I am not sure when this started happening but i didn't always have this problem. I used to copy and move large files with out any problems.

It will start copying the file or files and just stop after a few seconds. The box that shows the progress fades out and closes after a couple of seconds. It only works the way i have explained it. Renaming and copying does not work. I have to try to copy the file one time and then change the name for it to work. I can see where one might think this is a bad sector issue but i have 5 sata drives and this happens with all of them. The same goes for flash drives and my cell phone.

I do not consider my system to be broken. This is the only problem i have with it. Everything else works fine. I can still copy and paste, drag and drop regular and small size files. Reinstalling is out of the question at the moment. I have too much time invested customizing windows to my liking. Any other suggestion or comments are greatly appreciated.

Apparently i am both user349098 / user349894 please excuse me I am new to asking for help this is the first time I have ever asked for help not only here but anywhere on the net.

Comment: What happens if you, rename then copy?, or when you copy then copy?

Comment: It could be a bad sector on the target disc: if the partly-copied file contains the bad sector, it will not be used on subsequent copies.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by “fail”?

Comment: And by "let" in *"and let it fail after a few seconds"*?

Comment: In the future, please use the same account to make edits. What do you mean by “fade out”? The window closing, perhaps? It sounds like your system is broken beyond repair. I recommend reinstalling.

Comment: user349098 / user349894 / (whoever you are): Please register an account (preferably user349098, the one under which you asked this question) and use that account exclusively. That way, you can edit your question without needing to have it reviewed, and we know who we're talking to. (An anonymous edit was ***rejected*** 15 minutes ago; if it was you who "suggested" it, we had no way of knowing.)

Answer (score -1):

It often happens that when there are multiple type of files in a folder, it starts hanging. In such case. Which might be a reason while copying. I hope you are not renaming the file extension. This might be the reason behind easily transferring after renaming.

Though the scenario is weird, you may still look at [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20151217234010/http://technoratan.net/tips-and-tricks/how-to-fix-download-folder-hang-problem/).

Go to the folder properties, click on *Customize* tab, change the *Optimize this folder* setting to *General*. Save and Exit, further try transferring or copying your file.